# My file start in Visual studio, but just goes away immediately as exe file

Tags: visual-c++, exe

I recently started with programming C++ with Visual Studio Express 2015, I have compiled the .EXE file, but when I start this as admin and enter the input and as I then hit "ENTER", it just closes down immediately. I know the file works as I have tested it in VS1.

Appreciate any guidelines on how to make the exe file appear on screen for more than 0000001 milli seconds.

[image: screen shot of VS].

Comment: You are getting a preview of what happens when you create a shortcut to your program on the desktop.  Flash, bang, gone.  You need "Hit any key to continue" code.  Or always run it from a command prompt.  For now just set a breakpoint on the end of your main() function.

Comment: There isn't much code in this case. Please put the full code in the question, not just the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that windows closes the window when the program is done as a default behavior.

From [your header file](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) you can use `keep_window_open();` as the last statement.

It contains the following:

```
inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}
```

Another option, if you want to keep the program unchanged is to [create a shortcut and then modify the command that windows will use](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000738.htm) to execute it as follows:

1. Create a shortcut to your MS-DOS program or command.
2. Once a shortcut has been created, right-click the shortcut and click Properties.
3. In the Properties window, change the Target location to contain the `cmd.exe` command with the `/K` switch as shown in the example below.

Change

```
C:\My programs\test.exe
```

to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "C:\My programs\test.exe"
```

Comment: That doesn't seem related to this question or answer. D8016 means the options are not compatible. Some other settings for your project must be wrong. Please post another question with appropriate tags and details of what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: thanks it worked now. I needed to start a new project as there were some errors in my setting in pervious one.